# NaN error while converting float value to string

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to rotate the box via processing along with arduino and accelerometer. 
But when i ran println statement in processing ,it shows " NaN".  [ARDUINO CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3tAZ.png)

[Processing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rqnq.png)

Comment: I think, your analog values are getting zero or something like that. Please you could check the getting analog values for acceptable values. Good luck

Comment: Can you post the code rather than a screendump of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with one function which is there in arduino library named as

> isnan(yourNumber)

for that you have to include

> math.h

I have taking this reference from

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MathHeader

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` stands for "not a number".

It's not necessarily an error; it's simply what happens when you try to treat something other than a number as a number.

Your `val` variable must contain something that isn't a number, so the `float()` function doesn't know what to do with it.

Start debugging by printing out the value of `val` before you pass it into the `float()` function, then you can start figuring out **why** it has the value it does.

More info on `NaN` can be found in the Processing reference [here](https://processing.org/reference/floatconvert_.html).